# What features should my space-adapted cyborg have?

Tags: space, space-travel, trans-humanism, cybernetics

It's the far future: Thousands of planets and solar systems are colonized, some flavor of FTL travel works fine, and there are even nifty things like "inertial dampeners" and "artificial gravity" generators, although they tend to be rather large.

Furthermore, humanity went crazy when they discovered the answer to "are we alone?" was a disappointing *yes* and decided the way to fill the void was through radical genetics and transhumanism projects. Now humans of all shapes and sizes are scattered throughout space, some so radically changed that they can't easily be identified as "human" at a glance.

In my setting, the protagonist is an "infomorph" which means that they're essentially an uploaded human consciousness hosted on a computer housed in a flesh-and-nanomachine body. Besides being an infomorph and the advantages that that brings (immortality, consciousness copying, easy computer interface, etc) they are also of "spacer heritage" meaning that their body is optimized for space and life aboard ships/stations/etc. A spacer spends their time traveling on ships, trading with planets, and exploring and is a very nomadic person.

For example, some "features" that are part of this "spacer heritage" could be:

- An enhanced inner ear which allows perfect balance in shifting gravity along with an intuitive understanding of zero-g manuvering
- Skin which can rapidly change tone (eg from black to white) for thermal management when exposed to starlight
- A high resistance against high energy particles or other intense electromagnetic radiation
- The ability to perform spacewalks or be exposed to vacuum without damage (protected mucus membranes, internal air and power supply, etc)

Question: **Specifically what biological/cybernetic/phlebotinum "adaptations" or enhancements could a human designed for "spacer" life have in order to be able to:**

- **Work in a vacuum environment (possibly without a suit)**
- **Be better at repairing and maintaining spacecraft**
- **Survive the dangers of visiting diverse planets**

Comment: This sounds very much like [Neptune's Brood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune%27s_Brood)

Comment: VTC:Opinion-based, but it could also have been too story-based. SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. This is a fishing-for ideas question without any limits, restrictions, or conditions for best-answer judgement. As such, it's an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) question rather than an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) question.

Comment: I’ve voted to close because there’s no metric for what makes one answer better than another, which is the hallmark of opinion based questions. Consider restricting it to one aspect of spacer life and trying to come up with some success criteria people can have in mind when they answer?

Comment: @JBH Edited my question for more specificity

Comment: That's still very broad... "diverse planets" covers everything from barren rogue planets falling between galaxies, luxurious paradise planets, toxic demon planets, planets on the fiery side of the sun, and planets just outside the event horizon of a black hole. Why is the list you've created for yourself insufficient? (Note that the [help/dont-ask] specifically says to not provide your own answers and then expect more.)

Comment: @Willk Had to double-check: Neptune's Brood is by Charles Stross. He goes further in Glass House -- the main character was an army tank for a while. Because once you can upload consciousness, you can move it around to anywhere you could put a computer.

Comment: I think each of your bullet points could easily be their own well fleshed out question. We can really drill in on what the needs for each specific scenario as is required for your Spacer Infomorph (which sounds hella cool btw).

Answer (score 4):

You could draw inspiration from [John Scalzi's *Homo astrum*](https://oldmanswar.fandom.com/wiki/Homo_Astrum):

> Homo Astrum are Special Forces soldiers heavily genetically modified to adapt to life in space. They can maintain espionage and sabotage operations in space for weeks at a time. In combat they can sneak up to enemy ships undetected and affix pocket nukes.
> (...)
> Human-sized and irregularly hemispherical, similar to a turtle shell without an opening for ahead. Quadrilaterally symmetrical with four limbs of equal length, each having two points of articulation and ending in hands with opposable thumbs on either side.
>
> Their bodies are vacuum proof, have photosynthetic stripes, and contain an organ housing modified algae which provides fresh oxygen, moisture, and nutrients. The algae is fed with waste creating a contained system that allows them to live in space for weeks at a time.
>
> They are able to have sex in total vacuum by sealing the edges of their cowl with each other.

Answer (score 4):

I think that 2 features that would benefit the most would be an ability to change form and an ability to seal oneself from the outside world completely.

Shapeshifting would make exploration easy as your spacer can just mimic local forms and blend in easily (not all the time, of course, some restrictions, like total body volume, should still exist). It would also make all maintenance projects easier: Your arm is too thick to get into that hole — just make it slimmer. You can also make tools and weapons part of the body to increase control and dexterity while wielding them.

The sealing ability would provide protection from the dangers. If you want to make it less powerful, make it similar to a cacoon — great protection, but no action is possible. If you want to make it a superpower, make the sealing layer flexible enough so your spacer can move and perform tasks. You might want to include some kryptonite to balance things out.

P.S. Since you have nano-bots, make sure that repair protocols are part of their programming. That would come handy more than once.

Answer (score 3):

**All of them, just spread out.**

The greatest advantage of having a mind made of computer code is that you have options, because you can copy computer code to new hardware and — provided it's compatible, which you should probably ensure if you own it — just run it there instead.

Need to fly through the clouds of a gas giant? Copy your mental programs over to the computer systems of an aircraft or a huge biomechanical bird and off you go. Want to scurry through thin cracks on a tectonically active planet? Build a little spider body and start piloting that one.

I would imagine a well-to-do spacer with their own spacecraft would have several dozen bodies, each intended for a different sort of environment. Have your mothership carry an armored repair drone, and upload into it when you need to go out in vacuum and fix up the mothership. Get some heatproof bodies, some coldproof ones, some optimized for high-g, some for zero-g, some that fly, some that burrow...